# Разный цвет текста в одной textView

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Есть textView. в нем текст например `"Пример текста в текст вью"`.
Так вот, как мне сделать, чтобы первое слово "Пример" было желтого цвета, а остальной текст белого цвета?
И все это в одной `TextView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Spannable spans = new SpannableString("Пример текста в текст вью");        
spans.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Yellow), 1, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(spans);
```

вот тут еще примеры нашел
http://android-coding.blogspot.ru/2014/05/display-textview-with-multi-color.html

Comment: нашел решение тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-two-different-colored-text но ваш ответ верный так же

Comment: ну вообще то Html.fromHtm() собственно парсит html а потом делает тоже самое - Spannable :)